# How to store data from async function into global variable?

Tags: javascript, html, async-await

I'm trying to build a page that displays a random quote with a `<button>` that changes the quote for each click.

This is the async function:

```
let quote, author;


async function getData() {
    const response = await fetch('https://type.fit/api/quotes');
    const data = await response.json();
    const random = await data[Math.floor(Math.random() * data.length)];
    quote = random.text;
    author = random.author;
}
```

`getData()` works I can log `author` and `quote` into it, but I can't use the returned value outside of the function. I know that `async function` always returns a `Promise` so I have to use `.then` but I have to write new functions that use the data retrieved by `getData()` as:

```
function foo(quote, author){
....do stuff
}
```

The new function must modify the HTML code to change `author` and `quote`. The only solution that came to my mind is to create a function that contains everything (a huge chain of `.then`) and then pass it to the `<button>` via `onclick`. But it seems like a stupid and chaotic thing, and it wouldn't be a `Promise` anyway since it's the result of `.then`?

Comment: You can't store in global variable whereas can use as localStorage or directly update element under promise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create `author` and `quote` variables in the function to re-declare them every time the function is called

```js
const {quote, author} = data[randomNumber]
```

in here you grab `quote` and `author` keys in the called data

every onClick, these variables will be re-declared and you will be able to insert them as DOM Element innerHTML

You can check my solution How I would do that.

```js
const quoteText = document.querySelector("h1")
const authorText = document.querySelector("p")
const btn = document.querySelector("button")

async function grabNewQuote(){
  const response = await fetch("https://type.fit/api/quotes")
  const quotes = await response.json()
  
  let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)
  //Math.floor() -> rounds the number to down if random number is
  //3.99 it will output 3
  //Math.random() randomly picks up number between length size and 0
  
  const {text, author} = quotes[randomNumber]
  quoteText.innerHTML = text
  authorText.innerHTML = author
}

btn.addEventListener("click", grabNewQuote)
```

```html
<h1><h1>
<p></p>
<button>New Quote </button>
```

Also you could use `.then` but it would make big mess in the code and it would be less readable

if you are comfortable with `.then()` you can replace that following code up there

```js
await fetch("https://type.fit/api/quotes")
.then(response => response.json())
.then(quotes = > {
  let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)

  const {text, author} = quotes[randomNumber]
  quoteText.innerHTML = text
  authorText.innerHTML = author
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
const quote, author;
const myQuote = document.querySelector("#myQuote")
const myButton = document.querySelector("#myButton")

async function getData() {
    const response = await fetch('https://type.fit/api/quotes');
    const data = await response.json();
    const random = await data[Math.floor(Math.random() * data.length)];
    quote = random.text;
    author = random.author;
    myQuote.textContent = quote + "By: " + author

}

getData()

myButton.addEventListener("click", getData);
```

The takeaway is that you have to update your HTML within the async function, if you do it outside it might not be available yet because it's async, not sync. One way to do it, at least.